# C++ pointer to entire array. Memory deallocation

Tags: c++

On one of the forums I found a way to create a pointer to an entire array , rather than the first value . But how to initialize and access the array elements ?
Here is code of declaration:

`char (*p)[7];`

When I'm trying to free memory I get (_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse) error on line:

`delete[] p;`

How to fix it? I read that I need correct initialization with 'new'. But how to initialize it with 'new'?

Comment: That is a pointer to an array that has 7 elements, or an array of arrays that have 7 elements. Is that what you want?

Comment: It's a pointer so you need to dereference first: `delete[] *p`

Comment: It's pointer to full array that has 7 elements. It's not pointer to first element.

Comment: I don't think C++ makes a distinction between pointer-to-array and pointer-to-first-element-in-array.

Comment: "When I'm trying to free memory..." - that I never allocated... - there is no wonder this invokes undefined behavior. What *exactly* are you trying to allocate? A sequence of seven `int`? A sequence of `N` `int[7]` (eg. an array of array-of-seven-`int`) ? Be *precise*.

Comment: That's significant distinction. You can see all elements value of array in Debug Local list or you can see only first value.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner yes, it does. they're different types

Comment: I stand corrected.  Thanks guys :)

Comment: I want to allocate memory for pointer-to-array of char with 7 elements.

Comment: And you only need to use `delete` when you have used `new`.

Comment: @EvanCarslake then how to use `new`  with this `char (*p)[7];` Or how to delete p without errors?

Comment: Well, `char (*p)[7] = new char[1][7];` is certainly one way. Deleted with `delete [] p;`

Comment: @WhozCraig It's correct but I still get same error on `delete [] p`.

Comment: Error disappeared when I removed `p=&d;` where d is `char d[7];` - not pointer.

Comment: @VladislavVazhenin that would be code nowhere even *close* to being mentioned in your posted question, nor the sample therein. Trying to `delete[]` something that wasn't `new`'ed ?  Yeah, not surprised at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand good your problem. You said *create a pointer to an entire array*, but every time you declare an array with fixed length in c/c++, the variable points to the begin of the allocated memory. In other words, the variable stores the memory address where the array starts.

So, if you write `char p[7]`, you can get, for example, the third value in two different ways: `p[2]` or `*(p + 2)` . But, in this case, you can not use `delete`, because the variable has a statically memory allocation.

If you want to use `delete`, you have to create a dynamic array with the follow code:

```
char *p;
p = new char[7];
// using p var
delete[] p;
```

In the other side, with the statement `char (*p)[7]`, `p` is a pointer to the the variable that stores the first memory address of a fixed length array. In this way, you **can not** delete the fixed memory with the statement `delete p`, `delete (*p)` etc. To use delete in this case, you would have to allocate the memory dynamically like the example I wrote above:

```
char **p, *a;
a = new char[7];
p = &a;
// use ..
delete *p;
```

I hope it was useful :)

Comment: And what about  *a? You didn't delete it

Comment: Note that, in this case, `*p` and `a` point to the same memory allocated block. So, `delete *p` is the same as `delete a`.

Comment: thank you! I undestood it but thought that pointer must be deleted regardless of memory!

Comment: Hello! A pointer is an integer (with 8 bytes in 64bits processors) that stores the address of a memory block. I don't know if make sense *to delete only the pointer*, because you will lose where the allocated memory is (I think it is not desired) and the pointer is defined inside which scope of your code (like an integer of a function: `void foo(int i1, char *p1) { int i2; char *p2; }`. So, when the scope ends, the pointer is automatic deleted (note that the allocated memory has to deleted explicitly).